# Error: You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, tar

As the title says, I cannot run create-react-app.

```
You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

Doing this does not change the error. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

I entered this command to try it out and got a message that the tar was out of date.
`npm install -g create-react-app`

```
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path /opt/homebrew/bin/create-react-app
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists
npm ERR! File exists: /opt/homebrew/bin/create-react-app
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar

I ran the command with this reference.

However, the tar was not updated.
I have already tried all the published solutions, but they don't work. Can someone please help me? Please.

I tried clearing the cache but could not solve the problem.
`npx clear-npx-cache`

```
Need to install the following packages:
  clear-npx-cache
Ok to proceed? (y) y
```

I was able to successfully run the following command by specifying the version each time, but it is a hassle and I want to be able to run it normally.
`npx create-react-app@latest my-app`

Comment: They do not support `-g` any more. Consider not using that? Using `npx create-react-app` should use the latest one (if it's not installed globally)

Answer (score -1):

The "fish" shell I am currently using is node v18.0.0, so I downgraded to v16.15.0 and it works fine.

`fisher install jorgebucaran/nvm.fish`

`nvm install v16`

I had forgotten to lower the node version in fish because it had been working fine with zsh.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).